# cant decrypt sqlite after SQLCipher

Tags: sqlite, encryption, sqlcipher

Im tying to Encrypt/Decrypt file with SQLCipher on mac.

this is what i do to encrypt db :

```
sqlite> ./sqlcipher test.db
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'encrypted.db' AS encrypted KEY 'Sef*DFyds98fhsh2';
sqlite> SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted');
sqlite> DETACH DATABASE encrypted;
```

and after that i try this to open encrypted DB :

```
sqlite> ./sqlcipher encrypted.db
sqlite> PRAGMA key = 'Sef*DFyds98fhsh2';
sqlite> select * from tables;
```

and it gives me this error :

```
Error: file is encrypted or is not a database
```

one thing is my original db file is 1.6 Megabyte but after encryption it
turns into 226 KlioByte.

Comment: Can you hexdump the encrypted.db file and ensure that it is actually encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

If you type

```
sqlcipher --version
```

what do you get back?

If its something old like 2.x that is a problem.
[Building from source](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/introduction/) solved that problem for me. Should be around 3.8.x.x now.

also just curious, do you have a table called 'tables'?
sqlcipher has a built in method to exec this

```
.tables
```

*I guess it would have said "Error: no such table: tables
" if that was the case.*